# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::contains()

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::contains()

Here are my models:

DepartCity.php

```
class DepartCity extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array();

public function countries() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Country', 'depart_cities_countries', 'depcity_id',     'country_id');
}

public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Country.php

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array();

public function depart_cities() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('DepartCity', 'depart_cities_countries', 'country_id', 'depcity_id');
}

public function resorts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Resort');
}

public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Here is part of my code:

```
        $dep_cities = DepartCity::all(); 
    foreach ($dep_cities as $sletat_city) {
        $countries = $swc->getCountries($sletat_city->sletat_id)->GetCountriesResult->Country;
        foreach ($countries as $sletat_country) {
            $sletat_country_id = $sletat_country->Id;
            $country = (Country::where(array ('sletat_id' => $sletat_country_id))->first());
            if (!$country) {
                $country = new Country;
                $country->sletat_id = $sletat_country_id;
            }
            $country->name = $sletat_country->Name;
            $country->save();

            if (!($country->depart_cities()->contains($sletat_city->Id))) {
                $country->depart_cities()->save($sletat_city);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Getting error here:

```
(!($country->depart_cities()->contains($sletat_city->Id)))
```

Type of class $country->depart_cities() is Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany and there is no method "contains" but I cant understand how to do it works

Please help me with it :)

Comment: (!($country->depart_cities->contains($sletat_city->Id))) i removed the () after depart cities.

Comment: still not woking:
"Call to a member function contains() on a non-object"

Comment: change $country to $country = (Country::with('depart_cities')->where(array ('sletat_id' => $sletat_country_id))->first());

Comment: Added as an answer :) @user3828730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following;

```
 $country = (Country::with('depart_cities')->where(array ('sletat_id' => $sletat_country_id))->first());
```

and

```
 if (!($country->depart_cities->contains($sletat_city->Id))) {
       $country->depart_cities()->save($sletat_city);
 }
```